# Newbie, about Rake task syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, rake-task

In **Rake task** definition, like following:

```
desc 'SOME description'
  task :some_task => :environment do
    # DO SOMETHING
  end
```

What does the `:some_task` in `task :some_task => :environment` means?

Is it the **method name** which will be invoked in the `DO SOMETHING` part?

Can `:some_task` be any arbitrary string which describe the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, when you're creating a rake task, `:some_task` is the name of the task you are calling.

For instance, in this case, you will call `rake some_task`

You also could define namespaces for your tasks :

```
namespace :my_tasks do
  desc "My first task"
  task :first_task => :environment do
    # DO SOMETHING
  end
end
```

And then you will call `rake my_tasks:first_task` in your console.

Hope it will help you,

*Edit:*

As explained by [Holger Just](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just), the `:environment` executes the "environment" task and if you are on rails, loads the environment. This could take a long time but il also helps you if your tasks works with the database.

Comment: @Leem.fin This means that the task depends on your rails environment, which is therefore loaded first

Answer (score 1):

With your example, you define a task called `some_task` which can be invoked by calling `rake some_task` on the command line.

It will depend on the `environment` task which will be rune before your new `some_task`. In rails, the `environment` task sets up the rails environment (loading libraries, preparing database connection, ...) which is quite expensive and thus optional.